# Android: Renaming file keeps giving error

Tags: android

The file exists on the phone, but it does not change its name.

```
String filestatus = "failed"; 
        try{
            File file1 = new File(""+file);
            File newname1 = new File(""+newname);
            boolean renamed = file1.renameTo(newname1);
            if(renamed == true){
                filestatus = "succeded";
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

renamed stays false as defined in the beginning. Nothing else happens. Permissions like WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are available.

Comment: Why don't you try running it under debugger to see what's going on? Why do you catch exception and ignore it? What is that `""+file` thing? Bah, what type is `file` anyway?

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right way to get the file path, you should use Environment.getExternalPath() I think, or something similar, and then add the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the permission in your android application AndroidManifest.xml:,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard,"from.txt");
File to = new File(sdcard,"to.txt");
from.renameTo(to);
```